# Задача-ребус с собеседования

Tags: c++, задание-на-собеседовании

Задача-ребус:

что будет выведено на экран?

```
int n = 3;
int i = 0;

switch (n % 2) {
  case 0:
  do {
  ++i;
  case 1:
  ++i; 
} while (--n > 0);
}

std::cout << i;
```

Comment: Можно же в дебаггере по шагам запустить

Comment: @nick_gabpe можно и просто выполнить программу, но на собеседовании компилятора нет, поэтому надо объяснить ответ

Comment: Будет выведена ошибка компиляции, так как этот кусок не является валидной программой.

Comment: @VTT у меня всё компилируется

Comment: И что выводит?.

Comment: [А у меня нет](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JMIu8p6zUwIPJUI3)

Comment: @VTT вы забыли обернуть это в функцию `int main()` и добавить заголовочный файл `<iostream>`

Comment: @control Ну нет, это уже будет отсебятина, а то я могу это так обернуть, что выводить будет что угодно.

Comment: @VTT думаю, что большинству понятно, что надо оборачивать, не добавляя никакого нового кода...

Comment: Спецификации стандартных библиотек языков С и С++ не определяют поведение текстовых потоков, если последняя строка в потоке не заканчивается символом `\n`. Так что этот огрызок кода в общем случае ничего не выводит.

Comment: @control Как раз таки нет, во всяком случае на SO код в подобных вопросах должен представлять собой [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), который не подразумевает дописывания и додумывания со стороны читающих вопрос. И это очень здоровая практика, так как представления о том, что именно "понятно большинству" у всех очень разные.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При `n = 3`, остаток от деления `(n % 2)` равен 1, соответственно в конструкции `switch/case` происходит переход на метку 1 (`case 1:`) и переменная i увеличивается на 1.
Далее значение n уменьшается на 1 и проверяется условие выхода из цикла.

`n = 2`, что больше 0. Выхода из тела цикла нет, таким образом выполнение продолжается с начала блока `do {`. В теле цикла происходит увеличение переменной i на 2 (`++i; case 1: ++i;`). Конструкция `switch/case` в данном случаи уже не "работает". Значение n уменьшается на 1 и проверяется условие выхода из цикла.

`n = 1`, условие выхода из цикла не выполнено, повторяется предыдущий пункт. Переменная i увеличивается еще на 2.

`n = 0`, цикл завершается и соответственно конечное значение i равно 5.

Проверка [онлайн](https://ideone.com/Mox6J6)